# Draw Curve on Touch Points in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios

i want to draw curve with user touches two points perfectly...!but,no idea for this implementation for this functionality...!

Help with me any code or tutorial with greatly appreciated....!

Thanks...!

Answer (score 0):

Look at apple's '[Drawing Shapes Using Bezier Paths](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html)' guid.